# Any Maven JspC plugin will block some scanned jar file?

Tags: java, maven, jsp, tomcat, jetty

Tested both plugins individually: `jetty-jspc-maven-plugin` v9.4.44.v20210927 and `jspc-maven-plugin` v2.4.6 from io.leonard.maven.plugins. I run them in the prepare-package phase after overlays have been processed. My config for both are the same

```xml
<webAppSourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webAppSourceDirectory>
    <webXml>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
```

Compilation of over 200 JSPs runs fine for both but after, in the package phase when the maven-war-plugin is trying to move things around to create the war I get this error:

```
    Failed to copy file for artifact [org.owasp.esapi:esapi:jar:2.2.0.0:compile]: C:\path\target\local\WEB-INF\lib\esapi-2.2.0.0.jar: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

The file is not important, with Eclipse plugin I get esapi.jar, with leonardo plugin I get `log4j.jar` file. so they clearly have the same problem of somehow open the jar files for JSP compilation purposes and not letting them go afterwards. This problem appears only if the JspC plugin ran, otherwise no problems.

I am running maven command in CMD console. No other program that could block files are running. and I am not running maven with -T. Only thing that makes the error appear is when I uncomment the JspC plugin. Am I doing something wrong or is my assessment correct?

Comment: Typical windows file locking behavior.  Do you have these projects open in an IDE as well?  are you doing the maven build with threading `-T#` perhaps?

Comment: No to both questions

Comment: `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.` usually a problem with virus scanner etc. Or have you opened a file in an editor etc. ?

Comment: I already stated that the issue is repeatable. Only thing that produce the error is when I uncomment the jspc plugin in my pom.

Comment: I can trigger a 100% repeatable failure with any duplicate class scanner maven plugin on windows easily (just have the same project open in my IDE).  There is a legit some other process that has that same file open.  The solution is to figure out what that other process is.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt And my assumption is that the maven jspc plugin is the thing  that after scanning the jars files is not letting them go. Then when some other maven plugin tries to move those files it throws the error.